# Refer to a class, when we have an object of the same name

Tags: java, oop, object

*Please Note : This is an experiment, and not a real situation. I want to learn more, and hence I am asking this question.*

---

I have a class `ABC`, with a static method `method()`:

```
public class ABC
{
    public static void method(){
        System.out.println("ABC class");
    }
}
```

---

I have a class `DEF`, with a non-static method `method()`:

```
public class DEF
{
    public void method(){
        System.out.println("DEF class");
    }
}
```

---

Lastly, I have a class `GHI` with the following code:

```
public class GHI
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        ABC.method();
        DEF ABC = new DEF();
        ABC.method();
    }
}
```

---

The output is:

> ABC class
>   DEF class

---

I know the reason for the output.

My question is: *In such a situation, where we have an object of a class, with the name similar to that of another class, then how can we call a method of the class, which has the same name as that of a method of the object?*

In clear terms: **In this situation, how can I call the static method `method` of ABC class?**

Comment: Maybe refering to full qualified class name? e.g. `com.example.ABC.method();`

Comment: if fully qualify name is different then one way to use fully qualified name.

Comment: @Dr.Pelocho Oh Yes. You are right, but here I have no package. Any way I can do this here?

Comment: The obvious answer is that you would change your variable name, because creating a variable with the same name as a class that you are also trying to refer to in the same method is just writing terrible code to make things more difficult for everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In this situation, how can I call the static method method of `ABC` class?

You can create a `static import` of the `ABC.method()` (assuming that the `ABC` class is within the `com.package` package) and just call it.

```
import static com.package.ABC.method;

public class GHI {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        method(); // calling the static ABC.method()
        DEF ABC = new DEF();
        method(); // calling the static ABC.method
        ABC.method(); //calling the instance method()
    }
}
```

This way you could distinguish between the `static method()` and the instance `method()` (defined in `DEF`).

Comment: It raises an error saying: "cannot find symbol - class ABC".

Comment: Where do you put the import statement? What are the packages where these three classes are defined?

Comment: I have no package, and hence, the first line of the program I write is `import static ABC.method;` but it raises the error.

Comment: Well, actually you have my upvote. When I put these classes in a package, and then run the program, it works as you have said. Thanks for  your answer. I am waiting, if others have some other ways, which can make it possible without packages.

Answer (score 2):

There is no visible inheritance relationship between your classes `ABC` and `DEF`, so you are not going to be able to invoke static `ABC.method()` from any `DEF` instance reference (which `ABC` becomes when assigned `new DEF()`).

The confusion here is that `ABC` both serves as the name of the class `ABC`, and the name of your instance of `DEF`.

In other words, do not confuse variable names with class name references.

For ease of writing, Java variable names should be `camelBack`, see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html) for details.

**Final note**

If you *had* an inheritance relationship where `DEF` extended `ABC`, you wouldn't be able to declare `method` as an instance method in `DEF`, as it wouldn't compile.

You could only *shadow* `ABC`'s static `method` by declaring it `static` too in `DEF`.

Comment: That's why conventions tell you to use Upper first case for class name and lower camelcase for variables.

Comment: @Tokazio yep. OP clearly seems confused on the difference between their variable name and the class name because of that.

Comment: I am aware of the conventions. And, The first line of my question says that this is an experiment, and not a real situation. I know everything what you have said. But I want to know if I can do it here. You say no, but maybe others know how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Fist of all focus on how `variables/objects` are resided into `memory` that is in either `into stack/pool(literal) or into heap`.

*so here ABC-class and ABC-instance variable both as a same name comes in front of us, but actually where it resides is different.*

> so, if you call ABC before creating instance of DEF it's only one
>   that's why refer to ABC-class but after creating instance now it's
>   nearest than ABC-class. so , closest will reach/comes-in-picture first
>   (in terms of stack where actually it's resides)
>   theoretically/practically applied.
>
> this will help to clear in a more way,

```
 public static void main(String args[])
    {
        ABC.method(); // output : ABC class
        DEF ABC = new DEF();
        pck1.pck1pck2.ABC.method(); // output : DEF class , this will actually refer ABC class's static method...
        ABC.method(); // output : ABC class , this will refer DEF class's instance ABC because of closest will reach/comes-in-picture first (in terms of stack where actually it's resides

        /*
         * if you have default package means no-name for distinuges classes then 
         * need to create instance of ABC-class
         * */

        ABC obj = new ABC();
        obj.method(); // output : ABC class

    }
```

Comment: Hey, what's `concept`? Here: `concept.ABC.method();`?

Comment: ohhhh sorry it's my package name.

Comment: Oh! Creating an object is a nice way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer to me would be, this would not occur if following Java Naming Conventions :-)

Classes start with capital letters and variables with small case.

That being said and I know you mentioned that this is just a test and more of how would you access a variable of a class with the same name as a variable. Technically we should never have that if we follow the conventions correctly.

Interesting take though, well done!

Answer (score 0):

You must use fully qualified class name after you declare the variable

```
public class GHI{
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            ABC.method();
            DEF ABC = new DEF();
            ABC.method();
            packagename.ABC.method(); //Like this
        }
}
```

But a better approach is to follow naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers posted by **Konstantin Yovkov** and **Vishal Gajera**, I found another way to do it, using reflections:

```
ABC.class.getDeclaredMethod("method",null).invoke(null,null);
```

Here,

- `ABC.class` refers to the class.
- `getDeclaredMethod("method",null)` gets the method named `method`, which takes no arguments.
- `invoke(null,null)` calls the method, without an object, as it is `static`, and without passing any arguments, as it takes none.